# Tem algum problema em usar scanf com ponteiro void?

Tags: c, ponteiro, scanf, void

Fiz uma função que chama `scanf()`, passando um ponteiro `void` no segundo argumento:

```c
void read(const char *format, void *p) {
    scanf(format, p);
}
```

Testando com diferentes tipos:

```c
int n;
read("%d", &n);
printf("read int: %d\n", n);

float f;
read("%f", &f);
printf("read float: %f\n", f);

char s[100];
read("%s", s);
printf("read string: %s\n", s);
```

Fiz testes no Ubuntu 20.04.3, com os compiladores clang 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 e gcc 9.4.0.
Em ambos usei as opções `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. O código compilou sem erros nem *warnings*, e em ambos funcionou (todos os dados foram corretamente lidos e mostrados na tela).

Mas ["funcionou" não quer necessariamente dizer que está certo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png) (principalmente em C), daí a pergunta: este funcionamento da função `scanf()` (receber um ponteiro `void` e *setar* corretamente seu valor, de acordo com o especificador de formato) é algo esperado/bem definido e que pode ser usado sem problemas, ou isso foi apenas uma grande coincidência e deve ser evitado? Há casos em que poderia falhar (**excluindo, claro, os casos óbvios em que o formato não corresponde ao segundo argumento**)?

---

**Obs**: a ideia **não** é discutir os méritos da função `read` (se ela é inútil, ou se deveria verificar o retorno de `scanf()`, ou se deveria usar `va_list`/`vfscanf()` ou se há qualquer outra solução melhor, etc.). Quero apenas saber se este comportamento da função `scanf()` (aceitar um ponteiro `void` e "adivinhar" o tipo baseado no especificador de formato) é algo esperado (por exemplo, definido pela especificação da linguagem). E caso não seja, que seja dada uma explicação sobre o motivo de ter "funcionado".

Comment: No livro **C Completo e Total de Herbert Schildt**  menciona que o tipo void * é um tipo genérico de ponteiro ,esse tipo de conversão é  concedida porque o ponteiro genérico não contém referências sobre o tipo de objeto apontado, mas tem mais detalhes interessante nessa abordagem.

Comment: Pelo menos alguma coisa desse livro está certa :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pela minha intuição inicial eu não veria problemas, de fato o que ele recebe é isto, não tem sobrecargas para cada tipo. Em segundo momento considero inadequado porque poderia ter qualquer coisa e precisa bater com a formatação usada.

Porém a filosofia de programar em C é que o programador sempre sabe o que está fazendo e se tem algum ponto específico a ser observado está sempre documentado e quem vai consumir não vai ignorar a documentação. É diferente de outras linguagens que sabem que o programador vai ignorar a documentação e se deixar fazer errado ele poderá fazer. C precisa dar flexibilidade e não pode fazer muitas restrições, o programador precisa saber se funcionou por coincidência ou não.

Então minha intuição é que está certo se você fizer certo, se os dois parâmetros são compatíveis e tudo for feito entendendo bem o funcionamento da função. É o preço que se paga para ter a flexibilidade. Não querendo pagar essa carga cognitiva necessária, use outra coisa ou outra linguagem.

Como eu não domino C em todos seus detalhes, nunca pensei especificamente sobre o assunto e achei bem curioso, fui pesquisar. E alguém já perguntou sobre isso tendo resposta de quem provavelmente sabe o que está dizendo.

[O Lundin](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285965/285968#answer-285968) explica o que eu pensei que fosse, mas sem saber bem o porquê:

> Os ponteiros vazios são compatíveis com todos os outros tipos de ponteiro de objeto e, conforme mencionado em outra resposta (N.T. veja abaixo), 7.21.6/10 fala do tipo do objeto apontado, não do tipo do ponteiro. Isso é consistente com as regras de aliasing de tipo/ponteiro efetivo (6.5/6), que também devem ser aplicadas, pois o ponteiro passado não aponta necessariamente para um pedaço de memória com um objeto de um tipo declarado (poderia também ser um ponteiro void retornado de `malloc`). `scanf` deve ser considerado como um acesso "lvalue" seguindo as regras do tipo efetivo. Exemplos:
>
> ```
> float f;
> scanf("%d", &f); // comportamento indefinido, 7.21.6/10 e 6.5/7
> void* v = &f;
> scanf("%f", v); // comportamento bem definido, objeto f tem tipo float declarado e efetivo
>
> void* p = malloc(n); // localização apontada por p não tem tipo declarado
> scanf("%d", p); // bem definido, *p agora deve ser considerado como tipo efetivo int
> ```
>
> Para `scanf` fazer algum sentido, ele terá que converter internamente o ponteiro passado para um ponteiro para o tipo do especificador de conversão especificado. Qualquer informação de tipo que os ponteiros passados possam ter é perdida através da passagem do parâmetro *varadic function*/`va_list` de qualquer maneira.
>
> Notavelmente, há muitos cenários em que o `scanf` pode dar errado, portanto, deve ser usado principalmente para fins de depuração - não é uma função recomendada para ser usada em nenhuma versão profissional. Se o seu programa, por algum motivo, precisar usar a entrada do console, use `fgets` o máximo possível.

[Resposta do f~~](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285965/285966#answer-285966):

Da seção 7.21.6.2 desta minuta:

> [O] resultado da conversão é colocado no objeto apontado pelo primeiro
> argumento após o argumento de `format` que ainda não recebeu um
> resultado de conversão. Se este objeto não tiver um tipo apropriado,
> ou se o resultado da conversão não puder ser representado no objeto, o
> comportamento é indefinido.
>
> Portanto, de acordo com a especificação, é o tipo do objeto, não o ponteiro para o objeto, que deve corresponder ao especificador de formato. Um compilador que não interpreta o código citado para ter o comportamento que você viu neste ponto não seria compatível com as especificações.

## Conclusão

Como eu já disse em outras respostas, mas talvez não em todas, como deveria, `scanf()` sempre foi uma função para depuração e exercício, todo programador C sabe disso. Os estudantes precisam saber disso. Boa parte das funções em C são assim.

Em C o que importa é entender todo o comportamento, tudo o que pode acontecer e usar de forma que dê o resultado esperado. E essas respostas ajudam nisso.

`void *` é usado como o `object` ou `any` ou `variant` ou até `dynamic` de algumas linguagens, ou é só o único tipo que outras possuem (as de tipagem dinâmica normalmente). O uso dele é a escolha de cuidar da tipagem sem (muita) ajuda do compilador, é andar de bicicleta sem as mãos. Tem caso que isso é útil ou necessário, e traz sua responsabilidade. Se você cumprir corretamente pode usar que está certo.

Se fosse outra linguagem, a função `read()` poderia ser criticada por deixar fazer algo "perigoso", mas em C nem tanto, menos ainda pelo propósito da pergunta.

Comment: `scanf` é um scanner. **scan f**ormatted é a origem do nome. Não foi escrita para depuração ou  exercício. Foi escrita para consumir dados tabulares como arquivos `csv` no final dos anos 70. É é muito boa nisso.

Comment: É uma opinião possível, várias pessoas discordam.

Comment: Imagino. E várias pessoas como eu escreveram dezenas de programas para importar dados de sistemas e de sensores pra bancos de dados usando `scanf` em C. E hoje com BI e gigantescos arquivos texto para alimentar modelos de inteligência artificial `scanf` e `C++` são bem eficientes. Mesmo com os tais ponteiros :) Isso (CSV) é o passado de `XML` e `JSON` e claro precede a internet. `scanf` foi escrita para consumir dados tabulares.

Comment: Bem, imagino que várias pessoas tenham opinião diferente também de porque a função se chama `scanf` e sobre ela ser um scanner ou uma função para depuração ou exercício.

Comment: É, você é uma autoridade, Parabéns. Continue assim. Você pode imaginar o que quiser, e pode fazer como achar melhor, se eu gostasse da sua opinião eu a adotaria. E não estou dizendo que ela está errada, sua resposta demonstra isso melhor que o comentário, mas ela não refuta nada aqui, só que tem uma opinião diferente em um ponto bem específico. Nada muda o que o `scanf()` é ou como grande parte das pessoas pensam sobre ela. Pode todas essas pessoas estrem erradas? Pode. Elas estão perdendo alguma coisa? Azar o delas então. Pra mim faz sentido e minha é experiência é diferente.

Comment: Vou continuar *imaginando* que `scanf` é um scanner. Eu não queria contrariar a *panela* aqui, e nem contrariar o senso comum de todo programador `C`. A experiência de usar `scanf` para consumir dados de tabelas ou arquivos csv usando `scanf` em `C` deve ser coisa minha apenas. Vou usar para diagnóstico e exercício pra ver como se sai tal função!

Comment: EDIT: esse comment aqui tinha intenção de esclarecer uma dúvida imediata, mas dado o intervalo de tempo levanto o ponto em outra ocasião, portanto, estou removendo o meu comment.

Comment: Por que eu perco tempo com alguém que sempre se empenhou em distorter o que é dito?

Comment: Afirmar que o propósito do `scanf()` é depuração ficou rasa, não encontrei nenhuma doc falando que o propósito dessa função é destinada exclusivamente para depuração, consegue linkar uma fonte onde explica isso?

Comment: @Diego-maker a fonte sou eu e a já postada, eu considero assim. Muitas pessoas também, obviamente que não vou caçar toda a internet para colocar aqui, e por isso usam outras coisas quando precisa de entrada de dados. Você pode achar diferente e fazer como achar melhor. Nenhuma documentação vai ter esse tipo de coisa, não é função dela. O exclusivo é por sua conta. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2430303/221800

Comment: Perfeito aqui já resumiu a questão :)  *Nenhuma documentação vai ter esse tipo de coisa, não é função dela*

Answer (score 1):

> Quero apenas saber se este comportamento da função scanf() (aceitar um ponteiro void e "adivinhar" o tipo baseado no especificador de formato) é algo esperado (por exemplo, definido pela especificação da linguagem).

Sim, esse comportamento é esperado e isso pode ser usado normalmente. `scanf` não está adivinhando nada. E nada disso tem a ver com a especificação da linguagem.

`scanf` não aloca memória então espera um endereço para transferir os dados escaneados referentes a cada especificador que não tenha um `*`. Só isso. 5 especificadores, 5 endereços, por exemplo.

- A função não tenta fazer nada em relação a um possível *tipo* do ponteiro ou mesmo sobre a validade do endereço. É só um endereço para onde cegamente transferir o resultado da entrada a partir do especificador.
- a área pode não ser suficiente, como num caso em que passe o endereço de um `char` para ler um `long`. Deve levar a um *crash*
- para cada especificador satisfeito a função transfere os dados formatados para o endereço fornecido e nada mais. E soma `1` no contador de especificadores satisfeitos. Na saída retorna o total. Para 4 especificadores pode ler de 0 a 4 valores e assim retorna um `int` com esse valor para que o chamador possa saber quantos leu, ou `-1` em caso de erro.
- não ler nada não é um erro, contrariando o pensamento comum dos iniciantes.
- claro que transferir cegamente os dados para o endereço fornecido é arriscado e por isso por exemplo a Microsoft tentou por décadas emplacar a [família](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170) segura `scanf_s()`

`scanf` é um *scanner* e daí vem o nome: ***scan f**ormatted input*

`scanf` foi escrita para consumir dados tabulares, coisas como arquivos `csv` no final dos anos 70. E é muito eficiente nisso. É do tempo em que se fazia isso com scripts em `AWK` no `Unix`.

Não se pensava nessa função para uso de estudantes e muito menos para ler do teclado. A entrada padrão de um programa C não deve ser confundida com o teclado: teclado não é entrada formatada. `scanf`, `sscanf` e `fscanf` foram escritas para resolver problemas objetivos.
Entrada padrão de um programa C pode vir de redirecionamento, pode vir de um pipe, pode vir de um buffer de recepção, pode vir de um arquivo de dados tabulares... Raramente vem do teclado, exceto dos teclados dos estudantes e é um uso distorcido. `scanf` é um scanner para entrada formatada e o teclado não é tudo menos isso.

Pascal era a linguagem para estudantes, não `C`. `C` foi escrita para escrever o `Unix`.

`scanf` acabou indo para os programas de iniciantes por preguiça dos instrutores e autores, que não queriam ensinar a usar `fgets` para ler os dados e por exemplo `atoi` ou `atof` para converter, e assim distorceram o uso de `scanf` para encurtar o caminho.

Comment: O Unix foi escrito em assembly de 1968 a 1969 num minicomputador [DEC PDP-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7), a primeira linguagem escrita para Unix foi o [TMG](https://amakukha.github.io/tmg/TMG_Manual_McIlroy_1972.html) em 1972 e somente em [1973 que veio o C](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) o Pascal foi concebido 1968 mas [só chegou ao ambiente Unix em 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCSD_Pascal). A Entrada Padrão stdin é um fluxo de texto independente de dispositivo ou formatação, onde disparidades na formatação do fluxo se traduzem como Erro de Entrada/Saída.

Comment: Você tem versões curiosas da história. Um PDP-11/45 foi central nesse desenvolvimento de C e Unix e ele era usado por pessoas como Dennis Ritchie, Brian Kerningham e Ken Tompson. Talvez possa ler esse artigo https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html de Dennis Ritche, o criador de C

Comment: Você não leu o próprio link que mandou e não leu nenhum dos links que mandei pois entre entre eles está  incluído o link que passou

Comment: Trecho do link em questão *...Thompson se deparou com um ambiente de hardware apertado e espartano até para a época: o DEC PDP-7 no qual ele começou em 1968 era uma máquina com 8K palavras de 18 bits de memória e nenhum software útil para ele. Embora desejasse usar uma linguagem de alto nível, ele escreveu o sistema Unix original no assembler PDP-7....*

Comment: pois é. imagino que tenha lido o artigo todo!

Comment: Quando estavam portando Unix para o novo PDP-11/45 nos lab. Bell Ken Thompson resolveu usar a linguagem `C` desenvolvida pelo colega Dennis porque tinha pouco tempo e queria terminar durantes as férias de sua mulher, e em Assembler estava indo devagar. E ele só tinha um mês em que poderia trabalhar até mais tarde. Ele, Ken, sempre diz isso em entrevistas e conferências. E eu imaginava que seria história conhecida.

Comment: Então essa história que você está fazendo confusão é conhecida sim, é história da criação da linguagem C e quando ocorreu foi posterior a criação do Unix como já dito.

Comment: Caso não tenha entendido o que você proprio escreveu, para ocorrer esse trecho *"...Quando estavam portando Unix para o novo PDP-11/45..."*, ele só pode portar algo que já existe ou seja ele portou o já existente Unix escrito em assembly de 1968 a 1969 num minicomputador DEC PDP-7, para para o novo PDP-11/45

Comment: Unix passou de algo embrionário no PDP-7 para depois um PDP-10 e depois um PDP-11. `C` veio de `B` que veio de `TMG`. Tudo isso era conduzido por colegas de corredor na mesma empresa e ao mesmo tempo. E `Unix` só passou a ser algo sério a partir de `C` e do PDP-11. Nessa conversa https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY6q5dv_B-o pode ouvir Ken Thompson contando a história, ao lado de B. Kernighan.

Comment: Que bom que você entendeu que o Unix foi inicialmente escrito em assembly num DEC PDP-7.